# Can a delegate carry parameters?

Tags: c#, parameters, delegates

Let's say I have a function

```
public void SendMessage(Message message)
{
   // perform send message action
}
```

Can I create a delegate for this kind of function? If so, how can I pass a message when I use the delegate?

In my case, the function is used by Thread. Whenever there is an event, I need to send a message to the server, to keep the record. I also need to keep it running in background, so that it won't affect the application. However, the threading needs to use delegate

```
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SendMessage));
```

and I don't know how to pass the message into the delegate. Thanks.

Comment: They can have a return value as well. Useful for predicate and sort-functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a ParametizedThreadStart. See here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart.aspx

Comment: That is a specialized delegate used by the threading infrastructure. Using it outside of that context doesn't make much sense. He is better off creating his own delegate, or as Mehrdad said above, use `Action<T>`.

Comment: Look at his question again. He specifically says this question is in refernce to passing a parameter to a Thread to be run in the background :-P

Comment: Ah yes, you are correct. Sorry about that, it's too late to take back my downvote. You have the best answer of all here.

Comment: Its cool :) I can't remember how many times i've misread a question.

Answer (score 11):

Sure

```
public delegate void DelWithSingleParameter(Message m);
```

Passing a message can be done with the following

```
DelWithSingleParameter d1 = new DelWithSingleParameter(this.SomeMethod);
d1(new Message());
```

Also as @Mehrdad pointed out in newer versions of the framework you no longer need to define such delegates.  Instead reuse the existing `Action<T>` delegate for this type of operation.

```
Action<Message> d1 = new Action<Message>(this.SomeMethod);
d1(new Message());
```

Comment: or simply `Action<Message>` ;)

Comment: 1+. In newer versions of the language you can omit the "new Action<>" as well, as you surely know ;)

Comment: @Skurmedel or I could go the other way and use `var` instead of an explicit variable type ;)

Comment: Interestingly, `Action<T>` (with a single type param) has been around forever now (since .NET 2.0) and is declared in `mscorlib.dll` but the other variants (including the non-generic one) are side effects of LINQ and came in 3.5; they are declared in `System.Core.dll`.

Comment: @Mehrdad this changes in .Net 4.0.  Now all of them reside in mscorlib and they are type forwarded from System.Core.dll.  Except for Silverlight where they are still in System.Core

Comment: I prefer to create a new delegate with a direct assignment of the method. It's just a little syntactic sugar, but I think it makes the intention more clear: `DelWithSingleParameter d1 = this.SomeMethod;`

Comment: @Jared: Isn't Silverlight 4 supposed to be compatible with .NET 4.0 in core assemblies?

Comment: @Mehrdad, yes AFAIK.  It is compatible in the sense that from a compile stand point the difference doesn't matter due to the type forwarder.  But yes there is a functional difference if you depend on the assembly where these values live.  This is a bad choice though given that we've already moved Func from System.Core -> mscorlib

Answer (score 3):

sure, just define the delegate that way:

```
 delegate void SendMessageDelegate(Message message);
```

Then just invoke it as normal:

```
 public void InvokeDelegate(SendMessageDelegate del) 
 {
      del(new Message());
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/900fyy8e(VS.71).aspx) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do thing like that

```
object whatYouNeedToPass = new object();

Thread t = new Thread( () => 
{
    // whatYouNeedToPass is still here, you can do what ever you want :)
});

t.Start();
```